# Spacing between \cdots and binary operators

Tags: spacing, catcodes

I use `\cdots` to denote omitted terms in my sum, and expect it to have the same amount of spacing around it as if it were a usual term. Yet things are working a little differently from what I expect. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}\noindent
$a+  \cdots  +c$\\
$a+{}\cdots{}+c$\\
$a+  b       +c$\\
$a+{}b     {}+c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Around an "ordinary" term like `b`, adding pairs of braces does not change the spacing, which we see is indeed true. Around `\cdots` the same is no true. Usually it feels semantically correct to "quarantine" everything inside two pairs of braces to make binary operators respect it as "ordinary" and add the correct spacing between "binary operators" and "ordinary" stuff; yet curiously, in my example the spacing without braces happens to appear better, and I don't know if another mechanism is at work. Hence my questions are:

What accounts for this phenomenon in the first place?

Which is the better (semantically correct) practice--to add the braces or not?

If it's better to add the braces every time, is there a general patch that allows me to avoid typing braces every time?

I admit that my use of pairs of braces is kind of cargo cult programming because I don't have comprehensive understanding of why it works. Any explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\cdots` is a `\mathbin` so it spaces like `+` not like a `\mathord` such as `b`

The intended space comes from `+\cdots+` if you do  `+{}\cdots{}+` it is essentially double spaced as you get space from `\mathbin` on *both* sides of the invisible `{}` mathord.

Comment: Thanks, this explains the whole matter. However, why is it made a \mathbin—is it used in math literature as a binary operator at all? Would it be good practice to simply change it into a \mathord?

Comment: @LongHorn `\mathbin` gives reasonable spacing for `+\cdots+` and for `x\cdots x`  if it was mathord the latter would be too tight. In general, avoid adding spurious `{}` unlike text mode it's not just an empty group. In math it makes a mathord atom and has, as you show, many effects on spacing, not all good

Comment: You might want to mention that the recommended command is `\dotsb`, not `\cdots`, at least when using `amsmath`.

Comment: @Gaussler well the question is about spacing not logically oriented markup and `\dotsb` is defined as `\let\dotsb\cdots` so spacing is identical.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know, but they carry different semantic meaning (or rather, `\cdots` caries no semantic meaning at all).

Comment: @Gaussler neither does `b` and the question is about spacing not semantic markup.